# Angularjs Render external HTML

Tags: angularjs

In angular js how can, I render external HTML. I am getting HTML in response from the server.
and then storing that HTML in a variable `$scope.my_var = res.data` and then I want to render that HTML how can I do that.
HTML in sample response can be like as follows

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\">
    <style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color:#fff;}</style>
  </head>
  <body onload=\"return window.document.echoForm.submit()\">
  <form name=\"echoForm\" method=\"POST\" accept-charset=\"UTF-8\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" >
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
\n"
```

I want to display this HTML content. However, I haved used `ngSanitize` and `ng-bind-html` but it is not working for `form` and `input` tab only displaying value of title tag

Answer (score 1):

Normally that should work:

```html
<div ng-bind-html="my_var"></div>
```

Sometimes you also need to trust the source (see [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)).

However, I think it's related to your HTML, because you may not include a whole html with body and head into an existing site (except of using frames or something like that).
So I think, you need to strip that down to just the form-part to insert that.

For this issue I compile that code directly to also take advantage of any angular stuff using a dedicated directive.

To give you a hint:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('htmlView', function ($compile, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                $http.get("/html-endpoint").then(function (content) {
                            var html = content.data;
                            ele.html(html);
                            $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                        })
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to achieve this in a component instead of a directive?